# Own Object as Data in stl Multimap

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I'm writing an application, where I want to store strings as keys ans a custom Object as value

```
multimap<string, owncreatedobject> mymap;
```

Compiling does well, but I get a "Segmentation fault" when using the function insert
during runtime.

```
mymap.insert(string,myobject); --> Segmentation Error
```

A already added a copyconstructor an assignmentfunction (which calls the copyconstructor)

any idea about the "Segmentation fault?

Comment: Can you show some code on how you are inserting the elements and how you are using them?

Comment: Object *a;

a= new Object(),

a->value1 = a;
a->value2 = b;

insert (string a, Object b); (here the fault comes)

insert:
void Object::insert(string, a, Object b) {
  mymm.insert(pair<string,Object>(a,b));
}



The multimap is defined in the header

private:
    multimap<string, myobject> mymm;

Comment: does that even compile? if a is a pointer to object (object* a;) then how can you do mymm.inserrt(pair<string, object>(a,b));}

Comment: The Fault comes by insertion...

Comment: sorry i typed wrong 

insert("key",*a) of course!

Comment: it compiled, i just typed it here wrong, but then comes Seg....

Comment: It will be much simpler if you can edit your question and post the complete sample code with which the problem is reproducible. Also don't type the code, just copy paste from the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fiddle with your problem for the last hour and I think I got it.

Try using something in the matter of this code segment:

```
multimap<string,yourclass const*> mymap
void addtomap(string s,yourclass const* c)
{
   mymap.insert(pair<string, yourclass const*>(s,c));
}
...`addtomap("abc",&z);
```

In your given example you tried to insert without an iterator. The first element for a 2 element insert call for a multimap is the iterator. That's the reason for your segmentation fault and why one should use pair.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the comment you added for the copy constructor and assignment operator implementation, I found that your assignment operator implementation is wrong. Basically it is not copying anything, instead with the statement `Filter(f);`  , you are creating a local object named `f`. You can not call copy constructor like that. I suggest you to write a private copy method and use it in both copy ctor and assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to call the *insert* version that accepts a `value_type` of the multimap. In this case, just remember that multimap's `value_type` is a `std::pair`. Then, try this:

```
mymap.insert(std::make_pair(mystring,myobject));
```

*EDIT (after your comment)*: Your assignment operator contains an error. You create a temporary that serves for no purpose. Below is a suggestion of implementation using the *swap idiom*. (Notice that I don't know what are the types of the class member. Suppose they're a builtin such as `int` for example.)

```
void Swap(Filter const& f) //Create a swap member function.
{
  std::swap(SrcNET, f.SrcNET);
  std::swap(SrcPort, f.SrcPort);
  std::swap(DstNET, f.DstNET); 
  std::swap(DstPort, f.DstPort); 
  std::swap(FlowLabel, f.FlowLabel);   
}

Filter& Filter::operator =(Filter f)
{ 
  swap(f); //Swaps the copy created for parameter passing (pass-by-value) above.
  return *this;
}
```

Comment: I tried, but I get the Segmentation Fault still

Perhaps I have to write a Allocator for my object?

Comment: Then, please post a small but relevant portion of the code that reproduces the problem. Could be an error at the copy constructor, program logic in general, or something else. I don't think an allocator is the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have a buggy copy constructor and/or assignment operator implementation.

If the line

```
mymap.insert(std::make_pair(mystring,myobject));
```

crashes, it's pretty likely that some method which is executed on 'myobject' causes the problem. In this code line, the most interesting functions are the copy constructor and/or the assignment operator.

You say that you already added an assignment operator (which calls the copy constructor), but that sounds strange. Usually it's exactly the other way round; the copy constructor allocates resources (i.e. memory) as needed and then calls the assignment operator.

**UPDATE:** After reading your comment, here's how your copy constructor should look like:

```
Filter::Filter( const Filter &rhs ) {
    // Apparently no resource acquisition like memory allocation is necessary,
    // so just assign the rhs value.
    *this = rhs;
}
```

And here's the assignment operator. Note how it just copies over the values. Chances are that you don't need an assignment operator (or copy constructor) implementation at all because the compiler-synthesized code is fine for your uses.

```
Filter &Filter::operator=( const Filter &rhs ) {
    SrcNET = f.SrcNET;
    SrcPort = f.SrcPort;
    DstNET = f.DstNET;
    FlowLabel = f.FlowLabel;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: header:
    Filter& operator=(Filter const &f);
    Filter(const Filter &f);
cpp:

Filter& Filter::operator =(Filter const &f) {

    if(this != &f) {

        Filter(f);

    }

    return *this;

}

Filter::Filter(const Filter &f) {
    SrcNET  = f.SrcNET;
    SrcPort = f.SrcPort;
    DstNET  = f.DstNET;
    DstPort = f.DstPort;
    FlowLabel = f.FlowLabel;
}

Comment: Your assignment operator is bogus. It doesn't affect 'this' at all. Check my updated response for how these two functions should be implemented.